# Week starting hour gives previous week date instead of current week

Tags: sql, oracle

In our project we are maintaining a customers weekly spend. For that every week start we are resetting a customer limit.

Whenever customer doing a transaction we are updating his weekly spend by using the below query.

```
UPDATE SUMMARY 
SET WEEKLIMIT = (
       SELECT NVL (SUM (AMT / 100), 0) 
       FROM TRANSACTION 
       WHERE MOBILENO = :mobileNumber 
       AND TRUNC(TXNDT) BETWEEN (TRUNC (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'IW') - 1 ) AND TRUNC (SYSTIMESTAMP)
) WHERE MOBILENO = :mobileNumber
```

But the problem is customer who are doing transaction in `sunday 00:00:01 to 01:00:00 hours`, the above query updating the previous week limits
instead of current week.

```
SUMMARY

MOBILENUMBER  AMT TXNDATE    
0000000000    10000 26-12-2019 09:05:34
0000000000    10000 28-12-2019 11:05:34
0000000000    10000 29-12-2019 00:01:35
```

When I run this query in sunday first hour it returning

```
200
```

But from next hour

it returning only

```
100
```

Why the starting hour of week gives the previous week data.

Here is my NLS parameters

```
NLS_LANGUAGE        ENGLISH
NLS_TERRITORY       INDIA
NLS_CURRENCY        Rs
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    INDIA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CALENDAR        GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT     DD-MM-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   ENGLISH
NLS_SORT        BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT     HH12:MI:SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH12:MI:SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   Rs
NLS_COMP        BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: What's the timezone of the server where you are executing the query? Does the timezone differ from your other servers?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have updated my question with the NLS parameters.I am executing the query through procedure

Comment: You haven't got any where clauses in your update statement. Did you leave them out of your example or are there genuinely no where clauses in your actual statement?

Comment: No where clause is there. That query is the actual one

Comment: So it is actualy your select statement is returning the "wrong" data ? Can you update your question with some example data ? For example : 1. what is that select statement returning now and 2. what would you like it to return...

Comment: @Madhesh, something is wrong here, in your example data , values in column AMT are : 100, 100, 100. When you simulate your select it is not possible that it returns 100 or 200. Only maybe 1, 2 or something like that !? Because of this(AMT/100). Please check your question again, and the samle data, and correct what needs to be corrected...

Comment: @Madhesh if there is no where clause in the update statement, does that mean there is only a single row in the summary table? Because if not, your update statement will be updating every single row, which doesn't make sense. As already requested, please add in some sample data from both tables along with what you expect the output to be vs what you're actually getting.

Comment: @VBoka, sorry for the incorrect data I have updated my sample data in question

Comment: @Boneist,Update query has mobile number in where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue lies in your date manipulation. You are doing:

```
TRUNC(TXNDT) BETWEEN (TRUNC (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'IW') - 1 ) AND TRUNC (SYSTIMESTAMP)
```

and expecting that to make the start of the week a Sunday.

However, you haven't done this correctly - your logic says "take the Monday of the current week and subtract a day from it". If your day is a Sunday, that means it first gets the previous Monday and subtracts a day to make it the previous Sunday.

What you must first do is turn the Sunday into a Monday (by adding a day), truncate it to the first day of the week (Monday), and then subtract a day.

Which means your predicate should now look like:

```
TRUNC(TXNDT) BETWEEN (TRUNC (SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') - 1 ) AND TRUNC (SYSDATE)
```

Here's a test case demonstrating the difference:

```
WITH dts AS (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') - 1 + LEVEL dt
             FROM   dual
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 13)
SELECT dt,
       to_char(dt, 'Dy') day_of_week,
       TRUNC(dt, 'iw') monday_start_week,
       TRUNC(dt, 'iw') - 1 your_sunday_start_week,
       TRUNC(dt + 1, 'iw') - 1 actual_sunday_start_week
FROM   dts;

DT          DAY_OF_WEEK MONDAY_START_WEEK YOUR_SUNDAY_START_WEEK ACTUAL_SUNDAY_START_WEEK
----------- ----------- ----------------- ---------------------- ------------------------
01/01/2020  Wed         30/12/2019        29/12/2019             29/12/2019
02/01/2020  Thu         30/12/2019        29/12/2019             29/12/2019
03/01/2020  Fri         30/12/2019        29/12/2019             29/12/2019
04/01/2020  Sat         30/12/2019        29/12/2019             29/12/2019
05/01/2020  Sun         30/12/2019        29/12/2019             05/01/2020  <-----
06/01/2020  Mon         06/01/2020        05/01/2020             05/01/2020
07/01/2020  Tue         06/01/2020        05/01/2020             05/01/2020
08/01/2020  Wed         06/01/2020        05/01/2020             05/01/2020
09/01/2020  Thu         06/01/2020        05/01/2020             05/01/2020
10/01/2020  Fri         06/01/2020        05/01/2020             05/01/2020
11/01/2020  Sat         06/01/2020        05/01/2020             05/01/2020
12/01/2020  Sun         06/01/2020        05/01/2020             12/01/2020  <-----
13/01/2020  Mon         13/01/2020        12/01/2020             12/01/2020
```

You can see that for the two Sunday rows, your version returns the previous Sunday, whereas the amended version returns the current Sunday.

Comment: Thanks @Boneist, I have understand the issue. Problem solved. Thank you so much for once again

Comment: Instead of `TRUNC (SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') - 1` you could also use `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DY')` - however the result depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY`. Use it only if you can ensure that user session `NLS_TERRITORY` is **always** guarantied to be "India"! Using `IW` is independent from current user `NLS_TERRITORY`, so it should be the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Thanks for the guidance. For me NLS_TERRITORY is india. I changed my query to use TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DY').